# xsl with xml with attribute in root element does not work

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I use a sw that generates a xml file and i'd like to present that file in an html file, so i begun to create a xsl file to do that for me.
The problem is that i don't know how to address the errorlist root element due to the attributes. If i delete the attributes from the xml file the xsl works fine.

My xml file is:

```
<errorList xmlns="http://www.klocwork.com/inForce/report/1.0" version="9.1.0">
<problem>
 <problemID>1</problemID>
 <file>stdafx.h</file>
</problem>
<problem>
...
</problem>
</errorList>
```

My xsl so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Issues</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>ProblemID</th>
        <th>File</th>
      </tr>
       <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="errorList/problem/problemID"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="errorList/problem/file"/></td>    
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that if the attributes are present in the 'errorList' tag the output is a table with no lines but if i remove the attributes it works fine.

Comment: You got good solutions already. For an explanation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespaces#Namespace_declaration or search for "XML default namespace declaration".

Comment: LarsH,the default namespace seems to be html one here.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: true ... I think the explanation of default namespace declarations is still helpful though. Don't you?

Answer (score 4):

Add namespace declaration to XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:k="http://www.klocwork.com/inForce/report/1.0">
```

Then use it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="k:errorList/k:problem/k:problemID"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:k="http://www.klocwork.com/inForce/report/1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
```

and then reference it as `k:errorList`.

Comment: Uh... version="9.1.0"? Are you from the future? :-)

Comment: There's also version="1.0" :) Copied too much from OP's xml, thanks, I'll edit it out.

Comment: Bummer, I was going to ask you what features to expect in XSLT 9.1.0.

Comment: @eniac, yes, it's just that at first I copied it over with your namespace declaration and LarsH was teasing me about it.